# time not properly returned

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i have to convert a string to date. I am using date formatter to do the same.

**Code:**

```
NSString *stringDate = @"2010-06-21";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *theDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
```

this gives me the **previous date** and not the string date i passed. so i tried using time zone.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
```

this is giving me the correct date but wrong time.

I want only the **date**. How to get **correct date** and **truncate time** in the result.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
dateOnlyFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateOnlyFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateOnlyFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateOnlyFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

Obviously any NSDate you ask for will have a time element - you'll need to use the date formatter like so -

```
NSString *myDateAsString = [dateOnlyFormatter stringFromDate:theDate];
```

...then you could feed the string back to the dateFormatter to get a NSDate with zero time -

```
NSDate *myNewDate = [dateOnlyFormatter dateFromString:myDateAsString];
```